# UTF-8 not working when connecting to MySQL database in Python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, mysql-python

I am struggling to make Python play nice with my UTF-8 encoded MySQL database containing, for example, the Norwegian characters, `æøå`. I have searched around for hours, but have not been able to find anything that works as expected. Here is an example table extracted from the database:

```
mysql> select * from my_table;
+----+-----------------+
| id | shop_group_name |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Frukt og grønt  |
|  2 | Kjøtt og fisk   |
|  3 | Meieriprodukter |
|  4 | Frysevarer      |
|  5 | Bakevarer       |
|  6 | Tørrvarer       |
|  7 | Krydder         |
|  8 | Hermetikk       |
|  9 | Basisvarer      |
| 10 | Diverse         |
+----+-----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the data is definitely UTF-8 encoded. When running the below Python code, however, it does not give the output int UTF-8. What could be wrong with it? It has nothing to do with the zipping; the tuples returned by `cursor.execute(query)` has already messed up the encoding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="test",
                     passwd="passwd",
                     db="mydb",
                     charset='utf8',
                     use_unicode=True)

# Set desired conversion of data.
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.NEWDECIMAL] = float
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME] = str
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.LONGLONG] = int
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.LONG] = int
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME] = str
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME] = str
db.converter[MySQLdb.FIELD_TYPE.DATETIME] = str

cursor = db.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'

allResults = {}
cursor.execute(query)
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
rows = cursor.fetchall()
results = []
for row in rows:
    row = dict(zip(columns, row))
    results.append(row)
allResults['my_table'] = results

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

The `allResults` dictionary now contains:

```
{
    'my_table': [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'shop_group_name': 'Fruktoggr\xf8nt'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'shop_group_name': 'Kj\xf8ttogfisk'
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'shop_group_name': 'Meieriprodukter'
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'shop_group_name': 'Frysevarer'
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'shop_group_name': 'Bakevarer'
        },
        {
            'id': 6,
            'shop_group_name': 'T\xf8rrvarer'
        },
        {
            'id': 7,
            'shop_group_name': 'Krydder'
        },
        {
            'id': 8,
            'shop_group_name': 'Hermetikk'
        },
        {
            'id': 9,
            'shop_group_name': 'Basisvarer'
        },
        {
            'id': 10,
            'shop_group_name': 'Diverse'
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot really see what I am doing wrong. I am running the tests in Python 2.7.6 in Ubuntu.

## Update (changing tables to UTF-8)

I tried changing the tables to UTF-8 by dumping the database and changing the character set and collation in the dump file and then inserting it into a new database. For example, this part of the dump file corresponds to the example above. This is how it was:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_group_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

And this is what I changed this part to:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_group_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

However, this is still not working. The output is still the same as above. Running `SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';` now produces `utf8`.

Comment: Are your columns in UTF-8? Your output data looks like latin-1 (In UTF-8, `ø` is 0xC3B8, in latin-1 it's 0xF8). What does `select character_set_name from information_schema.columns where table = 'my_table';` say?

Comment: Hm, it seems you are onto something there. It gives two results: `NULL` and `latin1`. Not sure what the `NULL` is, but `latin1` is not what I expected/thought. The `latin1` one also gives `COLLATION_NAME = latin1_swedish_ci` for some reason. How can I work with this in `MySQLdb`? Oh, and just for completeness sake, the query is `SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';`. (i.e. `TABLE_NAME`, not `TABLE`).

Comment: `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` -- let's see whether it says `F8` or `C3B8`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your table, create your columns in UTF-8:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ...
    shop_group_name VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
);
```

If you don't specify the character set and collation, then MySQL uses defaults for character set and collation. Alternatively, you can set the defaults in [mysql.cnf](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html).

Comment: I tried changing my tables to UTF-8 as described in the update in the post, but it is still not giving proper output. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: I also tried creating a new database with `CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` and then creating the proper tables with `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`, but it did not change anything.